# Composite Primary Key having column with Allow Null true

Tags: composite-key

I would like to know the best practice. 
I have a table **Committee,** **Application**, **EmpInternal** and **EmpExternal** 
The primary key of Committee is a composite Key comprising of ***ApplicationID***, ***EmpInternalID*** and ***EmpExternalID***

Now since, **AllowNull** property is not allowed to be true in a column in composite key. What should I do to store committee members in Committee  table which are sometimes Internal and external. All the columns *ApplicationID*, *EmpInternalID* and *EmpExternalID* are **autonumber** in their respective tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
[EmployeeID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,    
[UserID] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](240) NULL,
[Rank] [varchar](150) NULL,
[Department] [varchar](240) NULL,
[College] [varchar](240) NULL,
[POBox] [varchar](120) NULL,
[Phone] [varchar](60) NULL,
[JoinDate] [varchar](200) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EmployeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeExternal](
[EmployeeExID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,  
[Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Rank] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[Organization] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  ( [EmployeeExID] ASC   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE =  OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY])
```

Comment: The ideal solution would consist in merging external and internal employees, then using a single EmployeeID. However, I don't know what exactly is the difference between these two tables, can you share them with us?

Comment: merging two tables does not seem to be a good solution since the tables are quite different

Comment: You should provide the tables definitions as well, we can not simply guess their structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flag record in the **Employee** table and **EmployeeExternal** table is a better solution than merging these two tables. the key of flagged record in the composite key remove the use of null in the composite key